# how to add a server provider name on visual studio 2013 Mvc4 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

**what should i do !!?**
i didn't download SQl server , i just setup the default one on visual studio 2013
as you see in the web config i tried everything 
the problem is it the default provider name is working but when i try my new provider name it never works and get me error

```
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
       </connectionStrings>
```

that's the default connection string !! 
**any idea's??**

[my web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiA2A.png)
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51BJL.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've defined the `connectionStrings` section twice (as you can see in the Detailed Error Information:

> Config section 'connectionStrings' already defined.

Delete the first one.

UPDATE:

Check the following: [Entity Framework Code First Migrations failing on Wrong Provider (3.5 instead of 4.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875246/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-failing-on-wrong-provider-3-5-instead-of)

And don't forget to add the required references: System.Data.Linq and System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll version 4.0.0.0.

Comment: of course i commented the old one but i get the same error